# Error en Manejo de ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Aldo Francisco Castillo compartió un enlace.
6 min

Hola buenas!
Recurro a uds esta vez con dos dudas de Java. Me encuentro realizando un laboratorio de la U para el cual en una parte debo almacenar coordeandas polares (x,y), para esto estoy usando el codigo que dejo a continuacion, pero al momento de probarlo falla como esta en la imagen, que podria ser?

La lista aux "coordenadasAux" aparece vacia cuando la imprimo fuera del if donde le agrego elementos.

Ademas, al agregar elementos, me cambia todos los elementos existentes con el elemento que estoy agregando.

Codigo:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> constructor(int filas, int columnas, int seed, ArrayList<Pieza> piezas, int gamePieces)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> newBoard = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> coordenadasAux = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dondePonerGato = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> parOrdenado = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> coordenadas;
    Pieza pieza;
    int numeroRandom;
    int sumador;
    int sumadorFilas;
    int sumadorColumnas;
    int verificador;
    int aux;
    int n = 0;
    int aux2 = 1;
    int gatos;

    newBoard = inicializarTablero(filas, columnas);

    while (n < gamePieces)
    {
        aux = 0;
        gatos = 0;
        verificador = 0;

        numeroRandom = (int) ((Math.random() * (seed + aux2)) % 19);
        pieza = piezas.get(numeroRandom);
        coordenadas = pieza.coordenadas;

        sumador = (int) (Math.random() * (seed + aux2));
        sumadorFilas = sumador % filas;
        sumadorColumnas = sumador % columnas;




        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
            {
                if (aux <= 3)
                {
                    if (i == (coordenadas.get(0).get(aux) + sumadorFilas) && j == (coordenadas.get(1).get(aux)) + sumadorColumnas)
                    {
                        if (newBoard.get(i).get(j) == '#')
                        {
                            System.out.println("gato encontrado, verificador = 1");
                            verificador = 1;
                            aux++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        aux = 0;

        if (verificador != 1)
        {
            System.out.println("//////////////////// iniciando busqueda de coordenadas ////////////////////");
            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
                {
                    //System.out.println("n: " + n);
                    if (aux <= 3)
                    {
                        if (i == (coordenadas.get(0).get(aux) + sumadorFilas) && j == (coordenadas.get(1).get(aux) + sumadorColumnas))
                        {
                            System.out.println("i: " + i + "\n" + "j: " + j + "\n" + "coordenada fila: " + (coordenadas.get(0).get(aux) + sumadorFilas) + "\n" + "coordenada columna: " + (coordenadas.get(1).get(aux) + sumadorColumnas));

                            parOrdenado.add(i);
                            parOrdenado.add(j);
                            System.out.println("par ordenado: " + parOrdenado);

                            coordenadasAux.add(parOrdenado);
                            System.out.println("coordenadas aux: " + coordenadasAux);

                            parOrdenado.clear();

                            aux++;
                            gatos++;
                        }
                        //System.out.println("coordenadas Aux" + coordenadasAux);
                    }// fin if aux <= 3
                    //System.out.println("coordenadas Aux" + coordenadasAux);
                }// fin for columnas
                //System.out.println("coordenadas Aux" + coordenadasAux);
            }// fin for filas

            //System.out.println("coordenadas Aux" + coordenadasAux);

            if ((coordenadasAux.size() % 4) != 0)
            {
                System.out.println("coordenadas aux: " + coordenadasAux);
                coordenadasAux.clear();
                System.out.println("coordenadas aux: " + coordenadasAux + " borrado");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("coordenadas aux: " + coordenadasAux + "\ndonde Poner Gato: " + dondePonerGato);
                dondePonerGato.addAll(coordenadasAux);
                coordenadasAux.clear();
                System.out.println("coordenadas aux: " + coordenadasAux + " copiadas\nen dondePonerGato: " + dondePonerGato + "\ny borradas");
            }
        }

        if ((gatos % 4) == 0)
        {
            n++;
        }

        aux2++;
    }

    //newBoard = agregarGatos(newBoard, dondePonerGato);
    return newBoard;
}
```

Fallos:

`//////////////////// iniciando busqueda de coordenadas ////////////////////
i: 8
j: 4
coordenada fila: 8
coordenada columna: 4
par ordenado: [8, 4]
coordenadas aux: [[8, 4]]
i: 9
j: 4
coordenada fila: 9
coordenada columna: 4
par ordenado: [9, 4]
coordenadas aux: [[9, 4], [9, 4]]
coordenadas aux: [[], []]
coordenadas aux: [] borrado
//////////////////// iniciando busqueda de coordenadas ////////////////////
i: 3
j: 3
coordenada fila: 3
coordenada columna: 3
par ordenado: [3, 3]
coordenadas aux: [[3, 3]]
i: 4
j: 3
coordenada fila: 4
coordenada columna: 3
par ordenado: [4, 3]
coordenadas aux: [[4, 3], [4, 3]]
coordenadas aux: [[], []]
coordenadas aux: [] borrado
//////////////////// iniciando busqueda de coordenadas ////////////////////
i: 9
j: 3
coordenada fila: 9
coordenada columna: 3
par ordenado: [9, 3]
coordenadas aux: [[9, 3]]
coordenadas aux: [[]]
coordenadas aux: [] borrado
//////////////////// iniciando busqueda de coordenadas ////////////////////
i: 3
j: 3
coordenada fila: 3
coordenada columna: 3
par ordenado: [3, 3]
coordenadas aux: [[3, 3]]
i: 3
j: 4
coordenada fila: 3
coordenada columna: 4
par ordenado: [3, 4]
coordenadas aux: [[3, 4], [3, 4]]
i: 4
j: 4
coordenada fila: 4
coordenada columna: 4
par ordenado: [4, 4]
coordenadas aux: [[4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4]]
i: 5
j: 4
coordenada fila: 5
coordenada columna: 4
par ordenado: [5, 4]
coordenadas aux: [[5, 4], [5, 4], [5, 4], [5, 4]]
coordenadas aux: [[], [], [], []]
donde Poner Gato: []
coordenadas aux: [] copiadas
en dondePonerGato: [[], [], [], []]
y borradas
//////////////////// iniciando busqueda de coordenadas ////////////////////
coordenadas aux: []
donde Poner Gato: [[], [], [], []]
coordenadas aux: [] copiadas
en dondePonerGato: [[], [], [], []]
y borradas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema que tienes es que realizas lo siguiente:

```
coordenadasAux.add(parOrdenado);
parOrdenado.clear();
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que a coordenadasAux no estas añadiendo la lista si no una referencia a esa lista, por lo que si después limpias la lista con clear, ese cambio tambien se va a ver reflejado en coordenadasAux y obtienes el resultado:

```
coordenadas aux: [[], []]
```

Para evitar esto podrías cambiar parOrdenado.clear() por:

```
parOrdenado = new ArrayList<>();
```

De esta manera limpias la lista, pero la dirección a la que apunta la lista cambia y los cambios que apliques a parOrdenado no se van a ver reflejado en coordenadasAux.

Saludos y espero que te sirva.

Comment: ohhh entiendo! muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te ha servido indca como respuesta por si se sirve a otra persona.